# Node.js ,multer File Upload Memory Leak

Tags: node.js, file-upload, memory-leaks, image-uploading, multer

i try to show around 15 files, the what i get is

(node:11266) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 finish listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:11266) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 unpipe listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:11266) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:11266) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:11266) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

i tried to use `process.setMaxListeners(0);` but it doenst work

anyway here my code

router.js

```
const upload_path = path.resolve(__dirname + '../../public/images' )

let upload = multer({
 dest: upload_path
})

router.get('/showImages', (req, res)=>{
  uploadService.showImages(req, res, upload_path) 
})
```

and here my controller.js

```
    async showImages(req, res, upload_path) {
    try {
        console.log(upload_path)
        let image = await Image.find()

        for (let i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
            console.log(image[i])

            fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(upload_path, image[i].filename)).pipe(res)
        }

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

anyone know how to solve this problem? thanks

Comment: That warning means that you're adding some listener somewhere that keeps accumulating rather than reusing the previous event handler or removing the previous one before adding a  new one.  We would have to know more about what object this is occurring on and then see the code that adds listeners to that object.

Comment: From the bit of code you show, calling `.pipe(res)` multiple times in a loop sure looks wrong to me.

Comment: yeah when i deleting the `pipe(res)` the memory leak message disappeared but the picture doesnt showed ,,

Comment: Well, you can't just pipe multiple images that way.  I don't know what you're trying to accomplish or what the client that sends the `/showImages` request is expecting.

Comment: yes i think i cant, i just tried to show get all image in my db,, that is ,, ok thank for telling me,, its awesome answer